# Why can't I reset the options on this knockout bound select?

Tags: knockout.js

I've tried everything just to get the value of a false/true dropdown reset (it should default to false, the first item in the array it's bound to) when the user clicks the reset button, which, eventually the same code will need called after hitting the Add button to clear all these form fields.   All of them are clearing except the vessel one.

The form:

```
<form data-bind="submit: addItem">

                <label>Category</label><br/>
                <div>
                    <select data-bind="options: categories, optionsText: 'Name', value: newItem.Category"></select>
                </div><br/>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label><br/>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" data-bind="value: newItem.Name"/>
                    </div>

                    <label>Description</label><br/>
                    <div>
                        <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="inputDescription" data-bind="value: newItem.Description"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <label>Price</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" id="inputPrice" data-bind="value: newItem.Price"/>
                    </div>

                    <label>Vesselizable?</label>
                    <div>
                        <select data-bind="options: vesselOptions, value: newItem.IsVesselizable"></select>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
                <button data-bind="click: hideAddPanel" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                <button data-bind="click: resetAddPanel" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
            </form>
```

Of course, vesselOptions is just:

```
self.vesselOptions = ko.observableArray();
```

In the code, the initial call to this function gets me my options for IsVesselizable successfully:

```
    function getVesselizability() {
    var data = ['false', 'true'];
    self.vesselOptions(data);
}
```

But my Reset function successfully clears everything else out, including resetting the Category dropdown by actually calling an API to get the array of categories.  But if I have changed the Vessel dropdown to true instead of false, it does not reset to its' default value of false, suggesting it has not bound or something.

```
    self.resetAddPanel = function () {
    getCategories();
    getVesselizability();
    self.newItem.Name('');
    self.newItem.Description('');
    self.newItem.Price('');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its probably because the value contained in newItem.IsVesselizable is still set to **false**. You are not clearing the value in your reset function. Simply add:

```
self.resetAddPanel = function () {
  /*Same as before*/
  self.newItem.IsVesselizable(true);
}
```

Of course you could also use the optionsCaption binding in conjunction with

```
self.resetAddPanel = function () {
  /*Same as before*/
  self.newItem.IsVesselizable('');
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: vesselOptions, value: newItem.IsVesselizable, optionsCaption: 'Please Choose...'">
</select>
```

Comment: I chose your first option rather than adding the optionsCaption, one note: I needed to actually surround the value for that property in single quotes for the selection to work properly.  (Also, I wanted false not true, but that's unimportant).  So:
`self.newItem.IsVesselizable('false');`
Thanks!